# How to select all related data from two tables having one-to-many relationship using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am struggling with Entity Framework as I would like to select everything related to one item from Item table and the other two tables `Label` and `ItemLabel`. The relationship between `Item` and `ItemLabel` tables is one-to-many.

I would like to write an IEnumerable method that will retrieve all the data related to an item. However, I don't know how to retrieve the all the data in the `ItemLabel` table.

Here's my schema:

```
Item Table: ItemId, Title, Description
Label Table: LabelId, Title
ItemLabel Table: ItemLabelId, ItemId, LabelId, Description
```

and here's my Item class in the Data Access Layer

```
public int ItemId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(Item itemObj)
{
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

    using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
    {
        itemList = (from item in context.T_Item
                    select new Item()
                           {
                               ItemId = item.IdeaId,
                               Title = item.Title,
                               Description = item.Description,
                               Labels = item.T_ItemLabel.FirstOrDefault(), <<<<<< Error
                           }).ToList();
    }

    return itemList;
}
```

Please note that I am using a database-first approach.

So could you please tell me how can I get all the labels related to each item I have in the `Item` table? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try to change this `from item in context.T_Item`  to  `from item in context.T_Item.Include("T_ItemLabel")`

Comment: @Lis, thanks for your help but what about the property inside the selection block. Could you please give a complete code snippet of your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting an entity type, you can just select it - you don't have to construct an object like you're doing. Simplest is `var itemList = content.T_item` because DbSet is also an IEnumerable but either of the following will work:

```
var itemList = (from item in context.T_Item select item);
var itemList = context.T_item.Select(item => item);
```

You can then access the `Labels` on each `Item` by just using the navigation property: `var labels = itemList.First().Labels`. The collections are lazy-loaded, so this involves another trip to the database. Add `.Include("T_ItemLabel")` to the `context.T_item` to fetch all the `Labels` in the original query.

Comment: thanks for your help. So there is no way to keep my code as is and modifying it to get the list of labels for each item, am I right? If not, could you please modify it for me?